# Tracking a specific group of visitors in Google Analytics

Tags: filter, google-analytics, tracking

I'm trying to find a way to track a specific group of individuals accessing my site. My initial thought was to set up a Vanity URL for these users to access the site through, and then set up a filter based on that specific traffic source and also a geographic region.

It is as simple as doing that? One issue I was wondering about was if these users return to the site at a later date, but access it directly or through a search. I feel this is where setting up a filter as stated above would not work.

Comment: It's impossible to really answer this question without know more about this group of users and what particular thing "groups" them together.

Comment: Hi Philip,

This "group" of users are people who are participating in a research study. At the end of the study they are to be given a link to the site. I am looking to track only those users who participated in the study - using that link provided to them. To further define the group, they will pertain to a certain geographic region (2 states).

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common approach to this type of problem is to use a [custom campaign](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863).

You've probably seen URLs with query params like `utm_source=newsletter` and `utm_medium=email`, etc. You'd just need to replace all of these values with the ones from your study and then you can run reports against just these users.

The nice thing about campaigns (as opposed to using a filter and a custom URL) is that if a user from a campaign comes back to your site later, Google Analytics will recognize that it's the same person and continue to attribute him/her to that campaign (with a few exceptions).

For more information on the exceptions and processing flow:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/campaign-flow

To learn more about the campaign parameters and values, go here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/campaigns-trafficsources

Comment: Thanks Philip. I was wondering if you have anymore information or can point me in the right direction regarding how Google Analytics will recognize the same user and attribute them to the campaign. Is this the case if the user enters the site via organic search lets say? Wouldn't analytics no longer attribute them to the campaign?